# Copiar una hoja con PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Buenos días,

Estoy trabajando con la librería PHPExcel para duplicar una hoja Excel.
Sólo me interesa su contenido, su formato no.

Lo primero que hago es abrir el fichero Excel:

```
$archivo = $_FILES['fichero_usuario']['tmp_name'];

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($archivo);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($archivo);
```

La pestaña que quiero duplicar está en la posición 1 (2a pestaña del documento Excel). Así pues, la siguiente línea que incluyo es:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByIndex(1);
```

Con la intención de posicionarme en la hoja que quiero duplicar.
A continuación intento obtener el contenido de la hoja que quiero duplicar:

```
   $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
```

E intento añadir la nueva hoja en el índice 4, ya que el fichero Excel está compuesto por 4 hojas (0,1,2,3):

```
$archivo->addSheet($sheet,4);
```

Pero algo estoy haciendo mal porque me muestra el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function addSheet() on string

La verdad es que es la primera vez que trabajo con esta librería y en ocasiones me cuesta entender su comportamiento.

Además, me surge otra cuestión: ¿cuándo hago cambios en la estructura del fichero Excel mediante esta librería debo hacer un "save" mediante el código fuente para ver los cambios?

Gracias de antemano por vuestros comentarios y ayuda.

Saludos,
Ricardo

Comment: Hola user. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Recuerda leer el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando `$archivo` :

```
$archivo->addSheet($sheet,4);
```

deberias usar `$objPHPExcel`

```
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($sheet,4);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Ok, menudo lapsus. Modificado. Saludos,
Ricardo

Comment: Si te ha servido dale +1 y márcala como valida para cerrar el tema.